# Sending progress from thread to gui

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a qt program with a statusbar. I am looking for a good way to update this statusbar. I could of course emit signals from the code, but I want to keep the gui and the 'real' code separated, and I want the code to be able to run independantly from the gui. The solution that I came up with, is to yield the subtotal to the gui, as is shown below in an extremely simplified example.

```
#in file1:
from time import sleep

class WorkerClass():
    def updater(self):
        yield 10  # total
        if some_condition:
            yield 'end'  # return early
        for i in xrange(1, 11):
            sleep(1)  # dummy for real task
            yield i  # subtotal


#in file2, in some function in the MainWindow class:
worker = WorkerClass()
u = worker.updater()
total = u.next()
self.progress_bar.setRange(0, total)
for i in u:
    if i == 'end': break
    self.progress_bar.setValue(i)
print 'done!'
```

I feel however that this is not the way it should be done. What is a better way to return the subtotal, without using qt code in file1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the progress bar as a (custom) [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). For example:

```
def dowork(observer=None):
  worker = WorkerClass()
  u = worker.updater()
  total = u.next()
  if observer:
    observer.progress_total(total)
  for i in u:
    if i == 'end': break
    if observer:
      observer.progress(i)
  print 'done!'
```

The observer can look something like:

```
class ProgressBarObserver(object):
  def __init__(self, progbar):
    self.progbar = progbar
  def progress_total(self, n):
    self.progbar.setRange(0, n)
  def progress(self, i):
    self.progbar.setValue(i)
```

And the calling code pairs them up:

```
dowork(ProgressBarObserver(self.progress_bar))
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: No, you misunderstood my question. File2 is the qt file, it is perfectly fine to use `self.progress_bar.setValue` there. I am looking for an alternative for the way that I'm sending the subtotal in file1.

Comment: @BrtH You might have misunderstood his solution: the observer allows to remove the coupling between file1 and Qt. file1 will only see the observer interface (the 2 functions `progress_total` and `progress`) which is defined in file2 with the Qt calls. So for instance, if you decided to change from Qt to Gtk, you'll only have to modify the definition of the observer class in file2.

Comment: @BrtH you should pass the generic-observer to the function in file1, and call it from there. that would be a better approach than using `yield` to report progress.  In most cases it makes little sense for the logic doing the work (in file1) to rely on the progress-displaying logic (in file2) to keep calling it to continue its work. they should be decoupled.

Comment: Oh, now I see, thank you. I appologize. Unfortunately SO won't let me remove a downvote, untill you make a edit, so if you could change a minor thing in your answer...